# Flutter detect when value passed to the statefull widget changes

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a statefull widget where am passing an integer to. I would like to execute a method when the value passed to the widget changes

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
 final String item;
 const Test({
  Key? key,
  required this.item,
 }) : super(key: key);

@override
_TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
 List<String> hh = [];

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  print("init state value is  ${widget.item}");
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container();
 }

 void getDataItems() {
  print("value passed is ${widget.item}");

  setState(() {
    hh = [widget.item];
  });
 }
}
```

So on the above i would like to detect when the value of string item passed to the widget changes and call the method `getDataItems` which will later update the list hh.
How can i detect when the value passed statefull widget has changed?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the [useEffect](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useEffect.html), which is based on the React hook useEffect.

Or you can hardcode it.

Create other integer: `late int lastCalledInteger;`

And check this in the build:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if(lastCalledInteger != integer) {
    getDataItems();
    lastCalledInteger = integer;
  }

  return Container();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply override [`didUpdateWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) on [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) to be informed of every change of passed in arguments. If you have multiple arguments you of course need to change what changed. For this [`didUpdateWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) provides you with the `oldWidget` as only parameter.

From the documentation:

> Called whenever the widget configuration changes.
>
> [...]
>
> Override this method to respond when the widget changes (e.g., to
> start implicit animations).